# Does Kate meet her target?

Tags: arithmetic, percentages

Kate sells cakes.
She has 80 cakes to sell for £3 each
Kate sells 50 cakes before reducing the price by 40%.
She then sells the remaining cakes at the reduced price
It costs Kate £95 to make the cakes.
Her target is to make a profit of at least £100.

I've multiplied the selling price with the amount of cakes sold and the balance with the reduced selling price but I am still getting the wrong answer

Working

30 cakes @ £1.20=£36 (40% of £3)
50 cakes @ £3:00=£150

£150 + £36=£186

Comment: could you type your working?

Comment: perhaps you made an eror in you calculations

Comment: We can't spot your error unless you include your computation.  should say, I have no idea what it is you are trying to calculate.  All the sale prices are set, right?  So she makes the revenue she makes and the profit is a simple function of that. There don't seem to be any unknowns.

Comment: Please show your work directly in your posting.  See also [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Comment: Seriously?  50 x £3= £150 is her income from the first 30.  How many did she sell at the reduced price?  What was her income from these? She had costs of £95 so what was her net income?

Comment: If the price of $1$ cake before the reduction was $1$£, what price would Kate sell it for after a $40$%-discount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is in the computation of the new price. Reducing the price by 40% means that the new price is the old price minus 40% of it. It would be $3 - 3 \times 0.4 = 3 - 1.2 = 1.8$. Giving you $30 \times 1.8 = 54$£ for the 30 last cakes. In total 204£.